# First open sub-menu second click go to page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a responsive menu.
I want to create the following:

First click open sub-menu second click go to the page.
I did create the following Javascript:

```
$('nav.mainmenu ul li').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().children('ul').is(':visible') != true) {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

When I click one time the sub-menu opens and the href is not working but when I click the second time it still is not going to the page.

The HTML:

```
<nav class="mainmenu">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-135">
        <a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/">Tours</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/touringcarverhuur/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Touringcarverhuur</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-239"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/events-samenmetdebus/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Events (samenmetdebus)</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-240" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-240"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/schoolreizen/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Schoolreizen</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-238"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/groepsdagtochten/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Groepsdagtochten</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
        <a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

So when someone clicks on `Tours` it should open the sub-menu below it and if the user then clicks `Tours` again it should go to the page `/tours/`.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @CBroe it is in the code, sorry forgot to add. Question is edited.

Comment: `$(this).parent().children('ul')` does not select anything. You are on the 1st level `li` element here, the parent of that is `ul#menu-main-menu`. That does not have any _children_ that are themselves `ul` again.

Comment: Why are you going up to the parent `ul` here in the first place? That could contain _multiple_ `ul.sub-menu`, so even if you used `.find()` instead of `.children()`, you could find multiple of those, so calling `.is(':visible')` on that would not make much sense to begin with. Just go and find the `ul` _inside_ your current `li` - `$(this).find('ul')` (Yes, on that level, you could use `.children()` instead of `.find()` again, because the `ul` is actually a child of the `li` here.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find(".sub-menu")` to find submenu and then check if the submenu is visible show it else redirect to your given url

**Demo Code**:

```js
$(".sub-menu").hide(); //hide submenu
$('.menu').click(function(e) {
  //check is submenu is not visible
  if ($(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").is(':visible') != true) {
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").show(); //show it
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-135">
    <a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/">Tours</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-value="avc">
      <li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-241"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/touringcarverhuur/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Touringcarverhuur</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-239"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/events-samenmetdebus/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Events (samenmetdebus)</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-240" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-240"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/schoolreizen/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Schoolreizen</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-238"><a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/tours/groepsdagtochten/"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Groepsdagtochten</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
    <a href="https://www.vanderwou.bvdodev.nl/contact/">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```